# Sending JSON Object instead of JSON string

Tags: json

I am working as an intern on a project. In that project me and my superior partner were asked to send **JSON object** through http GET/POST request in C++. I was surprised because we send JSON string through network. What is the logic behind in sending **JSON object**? This doubt was not cleared by my partner nor by my main boss.

Comment: Usually when people refer to something as a 'JSON Object', they'll still encode this as a string. When something has to be sent over the network, the terminology line blurs a bit, because it could be considered an object, a string, or a stream. So I'm guessing you just have a communication problem.

Answer (score 0):

A JSON Object is, practically speaking, wrapping the Java Script Object notation in braces: `{}`. The point being, your defining an entire (single) object, instead of an array of (perhaps incomplete) things. With the braces, as you probably already know, you may name the object followed by ':'.  For example:

```
{ 
  "My Object": 
               [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
}
```

You can't do the same with an array:

```
[    <--no option to name the array
 { 
      "My Object1": 
                   [1, 2, 3]
 },
 { 
      "My Object2": 
                   [4, 5, 6]
  }
]
```

Comment: So what I comprehended from your answer sending json object is helpful when it comes to send an array. Is it convenient for programmers to code or is it convenient in being sent over the network?

Comment: It is convenient in the sense that any (data) object is convenient -- it constitutes a logical 'chunk' of data. If there's some network error, you want to be confident that you've got a complete set of data or not.  With an object you can tell: did I get it or not; with a stream, it is more ambiguous:  how much of the stream did I get? can I operate on that stream or do I have to re-request it? In other words, data objects chunk, and therefore provide a conceptual "unit of work."